# Spark streaming hangs when streamingcontext.stop() is invoked programmatically

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to gracefully stop a spark streaming application running in yarn cluster mode using a file-watcher condition.I also set the condition

`sparkConf.set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true");`

which works fine when I run the application in yarn-client mode and issue a `SIGTERM` to terminate the application gracefully. Problem arises when I shift to yarn-cluster mode and I cannot access the driver machine to issue a `SIGTERM` and so I am using following logic`[ssc.stop()]` to shutdown the application programmatically. Observed behavior is that Streamingcontext stops and application hangs without processing the pending micro batches. Am I missing something here to shutdown the application in a clean way.

```
        Dstream.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1239370L;

            @Override
            public void call(JavaRDD<String> inRDD) throws Exception {
            try
            {
                 outRDD = applyTransformation(inRDD)  
                 storeToFs(outRDD)  
            }
            finally
            {
                if(!checkFileExists())
               {
                ssc.stop()
               }
           }
           }

           ssc.start()
           ssc.awaitTermination()
```